# What is the timeline for G1 Transformers?

Tags: transformers

I know that when you read this question at first you're thinking what are you talking about? So let me explain: They land on earth and later awaken in 1984. And somehow years later it's 2005! The only episode that tells us it's 2000, is 'Trans-Europe Express'. And the series ends in like summer of 2006. So, where do all the episodes or battles take place on the timeline according to the G1 Transformers?

Comment: Which series are you talking about? I assume it is TV not the comics (there are multiple universes and hence multiple timelines).

Comment: Yes I am talking about the TV series.

Answer (score 5):

Seasons 1 and 2 take place in 1984 and 1985.
The episode 'Trans-Europe Express' also takes place in 1985. The race was called 'Europa 2000' because the course was about 2000 miles.

Then, 'Transformers: The Movie' occurs in 2005, 20 years after season 2.
Season 3 takes place shortly after 'The Movie' and season 4 (just one 3-part episode) ends in 2007 (according to the [transformers wiki](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Generation_1_cartoon_timeline#2007)).

You can notice the 20 year difference because Spike is a boy during the first two seasons but a grown man during season 3.

Comment: The map of the Europa 2000 has some [very interesting implications](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Europa_2000) about the political state of Europe in the G1 universe.

Comment: Okay, Because it gets a little confusing along the lines of dates and where episodes fit in. And it helps to know these things if you are a nerd of transformers.

Comment: I guess I'm a nerd ;)

Comment: Well there's nothing wrong with being one. Thanks! :)